# Rails 5 order(:name) of has many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models, `product` and `variation` Product has_many variations and variation belongs_to product.  I am displaying the variations of the products in my template but can't seem to get `order(:name)` to work with the `variation` association--the controller code below wants to order the product name.

**products_controller.rb**

```
...
@products = Product.order(:name)
...
```

**product.html.erb**

```
...
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <div class="grid-filter">
   <% product.variations.each do |v| %>
     <span class="copy">
       <%= v.name %>
     </span>
   <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
...
```

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your question. Are you trying to show products ordered by name and for each one, variations ordered by name as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort Product based on Variations name, You might try adding order on the associations itself in the product model as following :

```
class Product
 has_many :variations, -> {order 'name'}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use order in the view as 'variations' is association too

```
    ...
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <div class="grid-filter">
   <% product.variations.order(:name).each do |v| %>
     <span class="copy">
       <%= v.name %>
     </span>
   <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order it in the controller:

```
...
@products = Product.order(:name)
                   .includes(:variants)
                   .order('variants.name')
...
```

Comment: I think the result will be products ordered by variants.name. Is it correct?

Comment: This code does the trick that he is looking for: it will order by product name, and for each product, it will show the variants ordered by name as well.